# What’s this button?

Tags: lighting, bathroom

I’m a renter and have no idea what this button is on my bathroom light switch plate. It’s in every bathroom in our unit, and including a half bath.

It changes color when you press and hold it, and the bathroom fan gets quieter for a short period, but automatically reverts to the original setting at some point. When we press and hold, the color goes from green, to orange, and then turns off, but then turns back to green as soon as you remove your finger. Also we can’t turn off the fan— it always seems to be on.

Don’t have and details on the fan model— it doesn’t have any distinguishing information on it, but looks like a standard fan.

I also haven’t seen the logo on the button before, and can’t seem to find out what it corresponds to. Would love anyone’s thoughts.

[image: Button]

Comment: Did you ask the landlord?  From what you typed it seems it a speed control for the bath fan.  If you don’t use it to turn the fan on then it must have a humidity sensor to activate it.  Really not enough info here to get an answer.  What’s the model number of the fan?  Or the switch for that matter?